# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS stuck in Logon Loop after switching GPU from NVIDIA to Intel

Tags: nvidia, login

Yesterday, in the bid to lengthen by battery life I switched my GPU from NVIDIA (Performance Mode) to Intel (Power Saving Mode) in the app shown below (screenshot borrowed) -- not the first time that I have done this but its the first time I have done so in a while. (No other changes to the system were made.)

After the change I got a messages saying that the change will take effect after I logon again. So I thought "oh well ... I'll do that later" but never did and powered down. Today when I booted up I could not logon again.

BTW, I have to logon to the console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> but that too fails. And if I overdo it the systems freezes. I was able to get to the console once through the recovery mode though.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the command line via recovery and ran

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Prior to running the above command

```
prime-select query
```

returned `intel`. Now it returns `nvidia`.